# SQL time stamp to millisecond

Tags: sql, vb.net, highcharts

How can I convert SQL time using a datetime stamp to milliseconds. 
I am doing a highstock chart using VB.Net

and this is my selection code so far

```
    Dim mydatalist As New List(Of XyData)
    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim strConn As New     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myCipConnection").ConnectionString)
    Dim strSql As String = "SELECT TOP 1000 DATEDIFF(second,{d '1970-01-  01'},dtmStamp)AS dtmStamp  ,dblReturnTemp  FROM tblCIPEventData  "
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, strConn)
    strConn.Open()
    sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
```

***I have a SQL selection***

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT TOP 1 dtmStamp ,dblReturnTemp   FROM tblCIPEventData"
```

The result looks like

```
2009-10-22 11:29:31.513
```

***How can I convert this to milliseconds***

Comment: How does the part above "I have a SQL selection" relate to your question?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out the milliseconds of a date you first have to compare it to some other DateTime.  By subtracting two DateTime objects you will end up with a TimeSpan object.  Then that TimeSpan object can be converted to milliseconds.  This can all be done with one simple line of code:

```
Dim milliseconds As Double
milliseconds = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 3):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186265

> You can use the SQL Server DATEPART() function to get the milliseconds
>   of a SQL Server datetime field returned to a Visual Basic application.

Example:

```
SELECT Pubdate, DATEPART(Ms, Pubdate) FROM Titles
```

Comment: it gives me 0 i don't know why

Answer (score 2):

For work we did using a timestamp that was in the form of DATETIME we did the following because we were not concerned with the time of day:

```
CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', left(a.mdate, 11)))*1000
```

The `left(a.mdate, 11)` gives data like = Apr 25 2012 (in readable format)

a.mdate = 2012-04-25 11:01:18.030

This is in the javascript time needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it SQL you can just [use Robert Harvey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318652/119477)

If you want to it in VB.NET and you have the following

```
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT TOP 1 dtmStamp ,dblReturnTemp   FROM tblCIPEventData"
```

The result will be a [System.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx)

To answer the question *How can I convert this to milliseconds?* we can make use of [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
Dim dtmStamp as DateTime
dtmStamp = sqlReader.GetDateTime(0)

Dim ts As New TimeSpan(dtmStamp.Ticks)
Dim milliseconds as Long  
milliseconds = TotalMilliseconds
```

This will give you the number of Milliseconds since 1/1/0001 12:00 AM

If you want the epoch to be 01/01/1970 you just do

```
Dim epoch as DateTime  = new DateTime(1970,1,1)
Dim ts As New TimeSpan((dtmStamp - epoch).Ticks)
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the job for me:

```
me.labelDisplay.Text = CDate(query.dateColumn).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Output:

```
2017-03-23 16:35:08.237
```

In case you want to get the milliseconds part use:

```
Dim ms as Integer = CDate(query.dateColumn).Milliseconds()
```